# How to create the setting page which flows over other page

Tags: android, mobile

[image]
The page below is the setting page of Evernote when the icon at the left-front corner is clicked. How to create a page like the setting page which flows over the main page? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for Navigation Drawer (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout):

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html